# PHPJasper não retorna dados do banco

Tags: php, laravel

Eu estou fazendo um relatório mensal de uma aplicação com Laravel 5.7, mas ele só esta retornando NULL do banco de dados. Estou usando o Mysql. Alguém pode ajudar?
Esse é o meu Controller.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;
use App\Model\User;
class ReportController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{


$output = public_path() . '/reports/' . time() . '_MidiaSocial';
$input =  public_path().'/reports/Sistema.jrxml';
$report = new PHPJasper;        
$report->process(
    $input,
    $output,
    array("pdf"),
    array(),
    [
        'driver' => 'generic',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'calculosorte'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'jdbc_driver' => 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
        'jdbc_url' => 'jdbc:mysql://'.env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').':'.env('DB_PORT', '3306').';databaseName='.env('DB_DATABASE', 'calculosorte'),
        'jdbc_dir' => base_path().env('JDBC_DIR', 'vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/bin/jasperstarter/jdbc/')

    ]
)->execute();
$file = $output.'.pdf';
$path = $file;

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    abort(404);
}
//caso tenha sido gerado pego o conteudo
    $file = file_get_contents($file);
//deleto o arquivo gerado, pois iremos mandar o conteudo para o navegador
    unlink($path);
// retornamos o conteudo para o navegador que íra abrir o PDF
    return response($file, 200)
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="midia_social.pdf"');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer a implementação como diz a documentação para retornar ele chaveado da forma correta.

```
$input = '/your_input_path/your_report.jasper';   
$output = '/your_output_path';
$options = [
    'format' => ['pdf'],
    'locale' => 'en',
    'params' => [],
    'db_connection' => [
        'driver' => 'postgres', //mysql, ....
        'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
        'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'host' => 'DB_HOST',
        'database' => 'DB_DATABASE',
        'port' => '5432'
    ]
];

$jasper = new PHPJasper;

$jasper->process(
        $input,
        $output,
        $options
)->execute();
```

Comment: PHPJasper\PHPJasper Object([command:protected] => jasperstarter --locale pt_BR process "C:\wamp64\www\pessoal\loteria\public/reports/BigGoldLoto.jrxml" -o "C:\wamp64\www\pessoal\loteria\public/reports/" -f pdf -t mysql -u root -p  -H localhost -n calculosorte --db-port 3306 --db-driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --db-url jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306;databaseName=calculosorte --jdbc-dir

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\pessoal\loteriavendor/geekcom/phpjasper/bin/jasperstarter/jdbc/
[executable:protected] => jasperstarter
[pathExecutable:protected] => C:\wamp64\www\pessoal\loteria\vendor\geekcom\phpjasper\src/../bin/jasperstarter/bin
[windows:protected] => 1
[formats:protected] => Array
([0] => pdf  [1] => rtf
[2] => xls
[3] => xlsx
[4] => docx
[5] => odt
[6] => ods
[7] => pptx
[8] => csv
[9] => html
[10] => xhtml
[11] => xml
[12] => jrprint))

Comment: Deu isso quando execute o exemplo acima. Você tem alguma ideia como resolver?

Comment: Meu Codigo ficou assim:

$input =  public_path().'/reports/Sistema.jrxml';
$output =  public_path().'/reports/';
$options = [
   'format' => ['pdf'],
   'locale' => 'pt_BR',
   'params' => [],
   'db_connection' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'database' => 'calculosorte',
      'port' => '3306',  
      'jdbc_driver' => 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
      'jdbc_url' => 'jdbc:mysql://'.env('DB_HOST', 'localhost').':'.env('DB_PORT', '3306').';databaseName='.env('DB_DATABASE', 'calculosorte'),

Comment: 'jdbc_dir' => base_path().env('JDBC_DIR', 'vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/bin/jasperstarter/jdbc/')]];
$jasper = new PHPJasper;
$jasper->process($input,$output,$options)->output();

Comment: Voce está usando laravel a única vez que fiz ficou exatamente assim 
https://medium.com/@eltonantunes_85873/relat%C3%B3rios-em-php-laravel-com-jasperreports-parte-1-9a37917846a1

Comment: Eu conseguir resolver fazendo algumas adaptações no codigo, mas agora queria passar um parametro de date para ter um filtro. Você me diz como posso fazer isso?